# Friendly_ID stops working at times, server restart necessary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I'm running a Rails 5.0.6 app with Friendly ID 5.2.4 and everything works fine except that after some time (sometimes a few hours, sometimes a few days) the friendly ids are not working anymore (instead of `/username/slug-of-user-post` it will become e.g. `/4/23`). A simple `cap production deploy:restart` fixes it.

Did anyone experience this kind of problem? Googled quite a bit but no luck.

Model:

```
def slug_candidates
  %i[title title_and_sequence]
end

def title_and_sequence
  slug = title.parameterize
  sequence = posts.where('slug LIKE ?', "#{slug}-%").count + 1
  "#{slug}-#{sequence}"
end
```

routes.rb: `get '/:user_id/:id' => 'posts#show', as: :user_post`

Controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.friendly.find params[:user_id]
  @post = @user.posts.friendly.find params[:id]

  render :show
end
```

Comment: Are you sure the same link is changed ? possibly you were using id instead of slug in url somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it just happened 5 minutes ago - again. It used to be something like `/peter-s/my-take-on-ci-cd` and it turned into `/52/82`

Comment: Can you post how you create the `slug`, the important code in `routes.rb` and your controller action?

Comment: Sure, will add it to the question!